# URL hash link doesn't shift page to element with matching ID

Tags: html, hyperlink

Currently this is my site

```
file:///C:/Users/CW/workspace/CASE-STUDY-CW/WebContent/index1.html
```

I have this code

```
<td><a href="#menu4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></a></td>
```

which I want to link to my div with id menu4 when clicked

```
<div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h2>Modify Defect Details</h2>
        <div class="form-group dropdown col-lg-6">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <label>Defect ID #</label>
            </div>
```

but instead it just add #menu4 at my site

```
file:///C:/Users/CW/workspace/CASE-STUDY-CW/WebContent/index1.html#menu4
```

what seems to be the problem here?
but when I'm using this

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Report a Defect</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">View all Defects</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Defect Details</a></li>
```

when I click on Defect Details, it switch to div id=menu3
hopefully this is also the same what I want with the clicking of glyphicon

Comment: Nothing is being "added" at your site. The browser shows the URL that the link specified. Why it's not shifting the page down is another question. Without a demo we probably can't help.

Comment: What makes you think that this should work? Are you following a guide that recommends this approach?

Comment: @AdrianWragg This is a technique in common use. ID hash references have largely supplanted name attribute references in URLs.

Comment: As you can see, there's no problem with this approach. https://jsfiddle.net/yttfqhhL The problem is somewhere outside of what you've posted. Without more information, this question is off-topic.

Comment: @isherwood They have, I just wanted to be sure OP wasn't simply posting data from a guide giving incorrect information.

Comment: I'll edit my post, sec.

Comment: @isherwood can you help me out? im really stuck with this

Comment: As I said, I can't see the problem, so I can't help.

Comment: @isherwood omg, while posting this post, I found out what's the problem, I just also need to use the data-toggle="tab" so that it switch to that div tab! hahahaha. well thanks anyway for trying to help! that was really dumb!!

Comment: @Chong Are you saying this doesn't work at all, or that it's not jumping on the page?

Comment: No problem. Please delete your question or post an answer if you think it'll help others. Be sure to explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I should have also use the

```
data-toggle="tab"
```

for the linking of glyphicon.
With only using this code

```
<a href="#menu4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></a>
```

It only adds #menu4 at the end of the url

```
ex. file:///C:/Users/CW/workspace/CASE-STUDY-CW/WebContent/index1.html#menu4
```

But with the

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></a>
```

It now switches to the div with id=menu4